# ASP.NET Core, MVC and OWIN

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating an old application to **ASP.NET core/MVC**. This application uses some OWIN middlewares to manage the authentication.

The middlewares works perfectly when they are registered using "UseOwinAppBuilder", however, in some parts of the application I need to get the "Owin context" to be able to work with the authentication. The "old" code does something like:

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authentication = context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("AuthScheme");
```

I know that in ASP.NET core I can manage the authentication using `HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync`, but if I replace the previous line by

```
var authentication = HttpContext.Authenticaiton.AuthenticateAsync("AuthScheme");
```

I receive an error:

"No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: AuthScheme"

I suspect the error happens because the authentication middlewares were registered using OWIN and not in the ASP.NET Core.

I know there are some objects that allows to create an "OwinEnvironment" and to access an "OwinFeatureCollection", but I'm not sure if this can be the way to access the "old" Owin context (and I don't find detailed documentation about how these objects works).

As overview: is there some way to access the "old" Owin context in ASP.NET Core in order to manage the Authentication with the registered middlewares?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what authentication middelware you're using, you might want to check your Startup.cs file to make sure the authentication scheme setting is correct.

For example, if you're using Cookie authentication middleware in ASP.NET Core...

```
var testOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
     AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
     AutomaticChallenge = false,
     SessionStore = new CacheTicketStore(cache),
     AuthenticationScheme = "AuthScheme"
};
app.UseCookieAuthentication(testOptions);
```

If you're using JWT token authentication, you'd see something like this...

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    // authority and app id settings omitted
    AuthenticationScheme = "AuthScheme"
});
```

Auth middleware also typically comes with some well-known constants, so you can use the default value from that provider.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
...
context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

If your authentication middleware is just set up with app.UseMagicAuthentication(), you can check if it takes options as an argument.